# Mac OS X 10.8 php.ini Include_Path for PEAR

Tags: php, xampp, pear

My current include path for php.ini is:

```
include_path = “.:/usr/lib/php/pear”
```

However, this is not working, because despite some files being found at the full path of:

```
/usr/lib/php/pear/HTML/QuickForm2/Loader.php
```

As an example, when I try to require_once this file using:

```
require_once HTML/QuickForm2/Loader.php
```

This doesn't work though, and despite restarting my Apache server and changing th einclude path to have a '/' on the end along with other silly things nothing seems to work.

Where am I going wrong?

By the way, I'm using XAMPP, but my PEAR files are definitely installed to /usr/lib/php/pear because I've opened them a million times from the Terminal with this path, as well as the fact that I can actually see it's all there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue by changing the include_path in **php.ini** from:

```
include_path = “.:/usr/lib/php/pear”
```

to:

```
include_path = '/usr/lib/php/pear'
```

For anybody else with the same issue, notice that I have **removed** the **'.:'**. 
I have also changed the quotation marks from double quotes **(")** to single quotes **(')**.

Hope this helps.